# need to get the parent pointer value, whats the best way to do it

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct node_ {

    avl_node node;
    some_struct *data;
}node_t;
```

Now if a function(API) returns me the pointer to data is there a way, I can get the structure node_t pointer?

For example:

```
node_t *a = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

a->data = malloc(sizeof(some_struct));

//some code

//a->data->key = some_val;

//avl_insert(a->data->key)


/* API to get the data, which return pointer of type some_struct*/
some_struct *temp;

temp = get_data(key)
```

Is there a way for me to get the the pointer node_t of the "temp".

Please, let me know what's the best way to get it.

Comment: There must be some other function within the API to return the tree node (as the parent of) `some_struct->data`.  `some_struct->data` is just a pointer and doesn't have any reference to what points to it.

Comment: I dont access to that API, I can request one but, currently for me to work can there be a way to get it?

Comment: What if my some_struct is the 1st element of node. I can get it right?

Comment: @Invictus: you simply can't get a pointer to the node_t from the value of its data member. If there is no API function for that, you're out of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get back to the node that contains the data, you have to build the association yourself. Perhaps the most straightforward way is to extend `some_struct`:

```
typedef struct my_some_struct {
    some_struct ss;
    struct node_ *back;
} my_some_struct;

typedef struct node_ {
    avl_node node;
    my_some_struct *data;
}node_t;

node_t *a = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
a->data = malloc(sizeof(my_some_struct));
a->data->back = a;

my_some_struct *temp;
temp = get_data(key);
some_struct *ss = &temp->ss;
node_t *back = tmp->back;
```

Alternatively, you can extend the AVL tree with an API to return the `node_t *` for a given `key`.

```
node_t *n = get_node(key);
```

Comment: You need to define type `node_t` before you use it in `my_some_struct`, and you need to define `my_some_struct` before you use it in `struct node_`.  They're mutually recursive structures.  You probably should write: `typedef struct my_some_struct my_some_struct; typedef struct node_ node_t;` and then simply define the structures: `struct my_some_struct { some_struct ss; node_t *back; }; struct node_ { avl_node node; my_some_struct *data; };` — unless I've made typos, that should work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for catching that. I think I covered it.